# Should I name the files in my solution all lowercase for SEO?

Tags: asp.net, seo

I read that an SEO best practice is to use lowercase urls.  Should I name my asp.net webforms project files lowercase as well?  Visual Studio doesn't name default documents in new projects all lowercase.  I'm not sure it matters since browsing to http://www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx will still work even if your page is named MyPage.aspx.

Can somebody enlighten me on this?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: here is one link: http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/  I think the point is to be consistent, so making all-lowercase does that.  Also am using dashes and not underscores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution files are not deployed or visible to webserver, so you don't need to worry about case in their names.

As far as aspx pages are concerned, most search engines *are* case sensitive when they index pages, so `MyPage.aspx` and `mypage.aspx` are **not** the same page as far as many search engines are concerned.

If you create pages that have upper case characters you could introduce situations where you will see search results for your page split between the lowercase and mixed case versions. This can adversely affect your the page rank, causing it to show up lower in search results than it would otherwise.

More importantly, you want to make sure that internally within you code you always build links that are consistent. If you're going to use mixed case - make sure you always use the same case. Just realize that you can't control what other websites choose to do - and many of them convert urls to lowercase. Also, most human users (when not copy/pasting) also tend to use lowercase for URLs.

Comment: great points!  I understand that to search engines MyPage and mypage are different and that I need to be consistent (which I am).  What this tells me is that IIS is not case sensitive so I don't need to care about the physical file name, case-wise.  correct?

Comment: Correct - the physical name is irrelevant. Only the name exposed to search engines in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I Recomend that you read this.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx

The answer is NO.
it doesn't matter if the files are lower or upper case, all that matters is where you reference a page, if you make for example an anchor tag  and your page is named aaa.aspx it's the anchor tag that is wrong not the page, and the pageviews will be splited, however if you do something like ScottGu points in his post you'll be saved.
Good Luck

By the way the title should be fixed it's not about the solution is about the files.